# ipython octavemagic

Tags: ipython, octave, oct2py

I'm on ubuntu with python 2.7

according to the [documentation](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/octavemagic.html) I should be able to get octave running from ipython:

```
%install_ext octavemagic
%load_ext octavemagic

('The file must have a .py or .zip extension', u'octavemagic')
```

If I try:

```
%install_ext bash.py
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-36b60e02c7c6> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'install_ext bash.py')
```

Complete trace [here](http://www.pasteall.org/34916)

`%lsmagic` gives a lot of magics and i tried `%%timeit arange(1000)` and it worked fine.

Finally, I tested the magic at the ipython commandline, as opposed to notebook; `%octave x = [1,2;3,4]` worked just fine.

**I'd really like to get octave running from ipython notebook.  Any ideas of where to investigate?**

octavemagic.py is in `<myinstall_directory>/IPython/extensions/octavemagic.py` as are the others i tried that failed.
My steps: according to http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/config/extensions/octavemagic.html

1. $ easy_install oct2py  (no problem)
2. $ easy_install h5py  
   `h5py/api_compat.h:21:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory` 
   (I do have it in a couple of places (octave and another 3rd party lib.  Found others who
   said that h5py is broken wrt hdf5.h, so I tried a full lib-dev install)

   $sudo apt-get libhdf5-serial-dev
   $sudo easy_install h5py
   Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py-2.0.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
   Processing dependencies for h5py
   Finished processing dependencies for h5py
3. Discovered I had a thin (notebook only?) version of ipython, so I installed the source from git and build it. Yes. I built it.  8)
4. `sudo easy_install nose pexpect irunner and ipython-dev`
5. launch notebook with `ipython notebook -pylab inline`
   Notebook starts and things work, except for the %magic octavemagic.  Also doesn't work for %magic bash or several others in

Comment: If it's already in `IPython/extensions/octavemagic`, you don't need to do `%install_ext`. Can you clarify what error you see when you do `%octave` in the notebook? Are you definitely using the same version of IPython for the notebook that you're using in the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Quite right, octavemagic is bundled with standard octave install, so all that is required is

> %load_ext octavemagic

my ipython commandline and notebook must be the same cause the only difference is:

```
> ipython
vs
> ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

I re-started the notebook and tried again.  Now %load_ext octavemagic works.  Perhaps i was just confused before by the errors associated with mistakenly [trying to install](http://www.pasteall.org/34982) 
Would be good if octave gave a message like "already installed" rather than the error with traceback as in the link.